# mysql - count issue

Tags: mysql

i need to count title by artist

```
SELECT artist,
    title,
    label,
    COUNT(title) AS countTitles 
FROM table 
WHERE domain = 'domain.com' 
GROUP BY title 
ORDER BY countTitles DESC;
```

but the result only gets me the count of the title - with different artists.

i want:

```
artist1 - title1a
artist1 - title2a
artist1 - title1a
artist1 - title1a
artist1 - title1a
```

i want to count like this

```
artist1 - title1a - 4
artist1 - title2a - 1
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not select columns which are not in your `GROUP BY`, even though MySQL extends this.

```
SELECT artist, title, 
    COUNT(*) AS countTitles 
FROM table 
WHERE domain = 'domain.com' 
GROUP BY artist, title
ORDER BY countTitles DESC;
```

Comment: what do u mean exactly? i should not select label if im not using it in group by?

Comment: interesting. what does it do? slow down the query?

Comment: @Dev-Ria You can't have columns in your select list that are not contained in your `GROUP BY`. You must be explicit since the `GROUP BY` is examined before the `SELECT`. MySQL allows for this functionality but it is not standard and you would be stuck if using any other RDBMS.